# Unable to get POST working with Yii2 RESTful API

Tags: rest, post, methods, yii2

I coded a RESTful API in Yii2-Basic using ActiveController and Basic Authentication. I can get the GET method to work, but when I try the Post, using Postman Chrome Extension, it throws an error saying "Method Not Allowed. This url can only handle the following request methods: GET, HEAD.".

Do I need to configure anything on my web server to test this, or require additional functions in the controller? I even tried this with a really simple table with two columns and also set the columns as safe, as hinted in another question.

Appreciate any help in this regard. Below is my current code:

```
<?php
namespace app\controllers;

use yii\rest\ActiveController;
use yii\filters\auth\HttpBasicAuth;

class TestController extends ActiveController
{
    public $modelClass = 'app\models\Test';

    public function behaviors()
    {
        $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
        $behaviors['authenticator'] = [
            'class' => HttpBasicAuth::className(),
        ];
        return $behaviors;
    }
}
```

The URL I am using to test is: http://localhost/test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was using the wrong end point. Using this end point worked for me:

http://localhost/test/create

Answer (score 1):

Try to splicitly allow the POST method for your action:

```
$behaviors['verbs'] = [
                'class' => \yii\filters\VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'index' => ['post'],
                ],
            ];
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :
        $params = \Yii::$app->request->post();

for reference:
https://forum.yiiframework.com/t/rest-api-model-create-problem/83651